# Is it OK to use Meta for announcements?

Tags: discussion, dnd-5e

I ask because something of interest has induced me to indulge in Thread Necromancy.

[OGL/SRD for 5e D&D has been posted.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/45024/is-there-a-ogl-or-gsl-license-for-dd-5e)

Comment: There is a badge called necromancer... you get fake internet points for what you want to avoid.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, not really.  Ideally you'd post it to the relevant existing question.  Failing that, announce in chat.  In fact, looks like you already did post it to a relevant existing question. That's enough. Meta isn't for announcements of that sort.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot about chat as I rarely use it.

Answer (score 10):

Meta can be used for announcements about the site *itself*, but not for other things. Meta's topic is just as focused as the main site, just in this case [the topic is the use and workings of the main site](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta). That makes it unsuitable for general news and announcements about things related to roleplaying games that don't impact policy and maintenance.

Answer (score 4):

The Stack doesn't have forum-type threads, so posting new content to an old question page isn't frowned upon: questions and answers never get too old to be modified with good content. We'll even [give out badges](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/badges/44/necromancer) for it! So if you're thinking of using meta to avoid "thread necromancy," don't worry, that taboo isn't indulged by this site.

Comment: *Yeeesssss. Become a necromancer, we give out shinies.*

Comment: I already have the necromancy badge.  I guess I was trying to level up to unlock new powers.